# Approximation of Lebesgue measurable functions by continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set; let $f\colon K\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ Lebesgue measurable function. Then for all $\delta>0$ exists a continuous function $\hat{f}\colon K\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $\lambda_n(\{f\ne\hat{f}\})<\delta;$
- $\sup_{x\in K}\lvert \hat{f}(x)\vert\le\sup_{x\in K}\lvert f(x)\rvert$.

$\lambda_n$ denotes the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*Proof.* $(n=1)$

We can assume that $K=[0,1]$. Let $\delta>0$; for known results exists a closed set $C\subseteq [0,1]$ such that $\lambda([0,1]\setminus C)<\delta$ and also $f_{|C}$ is continuous.Since the set $(0,1)\setminus C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, results:

$$(0,1)\setminus C=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (a_k,b_k),$$

where the intervals $(a_k,b_k)$ are disjointed. We define
$$
\hat{f}(x):=
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if $x\in C$} \\
f(a_k)+\frac{f(b_k)-f(a_k)}{b_k-a_k}(x-a_k) & \text{if $x\in (a_k,b_k)\quad (k\in \mathbb{N}$)}
\end{cases}
$$

> **Question 1.** How do you prove the existence of the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\hat{f}(x)?$$

> **Question 2.** How to generalize the prove to case $n$? Can you suggest me some text where this theorem is already present? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to Question 1:** we split into cases:

- If $0 \notin C$ and $C$ closed, then $0$ is not an accumulation point, so there is $(0,\eta) \subseteq (0,1)\setminus C$. The linear interpolation $\hat f$ is clearly continuous at $0$ in this case (a line is right continuous). In fact even if $0 \in C$ but $0$ is not an accumulation point, the same argument holds.
- The remaining case is that $0 \in C$ is an accumulation point of $C$. Because the restriction $f|_C$ is continuous, $\forall \epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $c \in C \cap (0,\delta)$ we have $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. Because the linear interpolation on $(a_k,b_k)$ takes values between the numbers $f(a_k),f(b_k)$, if both $f(a_k),f(b_k)$ are within $\epsilon$ of $f(0)$, then so will the intermediate values. Thus we have that for any $c_0\in C \cap (0,\delta)$, we indeed have $|x-0|<c_0 \implies |\hat f(x)-\hat f(0)|<\epsilon$, so continuity from the right at $0$ is proved.

**Answer to Question 2:** the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) tells that we can extend any continuous function defined on a closed subset of a normal topological space (e.g. $\mathbb R^n$) to a continuous function defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$ (and we can do so in a way that preserves the sup of the function, which your problem requires). If you already have Urysohn's lemma, [this link](https://planetmath.org/proofoftietzeextensiontheorem) provides a decent proof. Wikipedia has a nice [sketch of the proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) of Urysohn's lemma. There is also a proof of Tietze in the context of metric spaces, which may feel more concrete (though it is quite messy): [Easier proof of Tietze theorem in metric case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428804/easier-proof-of-tietze-theorem-in-metric-case).